# Remove part of string from "[" to the end

Tags: python, string, pandas, list, dataframe

Below is a snippet of my text file:

```
import re 
f = open('/Users/name/Desktop/university_towns.txt',"r")
f.readlines()

Langston (Langston University)[5]
Norman (University of Oklahoma)[1]
Stillwater (Oklahoma State University)[5]
Tahlequah (Northeastern State University)[2]
```

I have tried the following:

```
import re 
f = open('/Users/emreyavuz/Desktop/university_towns.txt',"r")
for i in f.readlines():
    if i.find(r'\(.*?\)'): 
       print(re.sub(r'\(.*?\)\[.*?\]', "", i))
    elif i.find(r'\s?\(.*?\)'):
        print(re.sub(r'\s?\(.*?\)\[.*?\]', "", i))
    else: 
       print(re.sub(r'\[.*?\]', "", i))
```

The **code above** should do this:

1) If the string contains here(abc) **remove(abc)**

2) If the string contains here (abc) **remove(abc)**

3) If the string contains [2] **remove [2]**

It is not giving me any errors BUT the 2nd line (elif) is not working...

Would anybody be able to give me a helping hand?

**Sample of output:**

```
La Crosse 
Madison 
Menomonie 
Milwaukee (Marquette University, University of Wisconsin–Milwaukee)
Oshkosh (University of Wisconsin–Oshkosh)
```

Comment: why you use ending `/` here?

Comment: @AlwaysSunny mistake! Have corrected above :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work without trailing `/`, I tried with regex `sub`, [REGEX](https://regex101.com/r/2Dlnxj/4)

```
import re
regex = r"\[.*?\]"
test_str = ("Langston (Langston University)[5]\n"
    "Norman (University of Oklahoma)[1]\n"
    "Stillwater (Oklahoma State University)[5]\n"
    "Tahlequah (Northeastern State University)[2]")

subst = ""
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)
if result:
    print (result)
```

**As Per the question edit and comment**, Using a single `if` condition, you can do what you want to achieve,

```
import re
f = open('/Users/emreyavuz/Desktop/university_towns.txt',"r")
for i in f.readlines():
    if i.find(r'\s?\(.*?\)(\[.*?\])?'):
       print(re.sub(r'\s?\(.*?\)(\[.*?\])?', "", i))
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Opps. posted and saw your answer :)

Comment: @Caledonian26 by the way you can use `\d+` in place of `.*?` to allow only digits

Comment: if I wanted to remove (University of Oklahoma)[1]: both the parentheses and the number,  
I would do print(re.sub(r'\(.*?)[.*?\]', "", i))?

Comment: I think you need this `\(.*?\)\[.*?\]`, see regex here: https://regex101.com/r/2Dlnxj/5

Comment: yes that works for me! And if I want a space between the word and the '(', I do: print(re.sub(r'\ (.*?\)\[.*?\]', "", i))?

Comment: @Caledonian26 exactly :)

Comment: that does not seem to be working strangely! Please see my amended post above :)

Comment: Add a `?` after your space character to make it optional

Comment: Have tried and that does not work:     elif i.find(r'\ ?(.*?\)'):
        print(re.sub(r'\ ?(.*?\)\[.*?\]', "", i)), doesn't the question mark make it not greedy (finds the first instance?)

Comment: Can you try this?  `\s?\(.*?\)\[.*?\]` not sure it will work or not because regex101 not working properly on my mobile :(

Answer (score 1):

We can try using `re.sub` here:

```
for i in f.readlines():
    print(re.sub(r'\[\d+\]$', '' , i))
```

This assumes that nothing would following the `[num]` tags occurring at the end of each line.  If some other content could follow, the above pattern would have to be adjusted.

Comment: please see my amended post above!